# Access API only from server side in SvelteKit

Tags: sveltekit

I already have the backend with an API for my application and now wanted to add the frontend with SvelteKit. Since I dont want my API to be available on the public internet I thought it would be a good idea to deploy the server in the same network as the API and only access it from server side. Now I'm stuck on how to exactly do that.

I am already using the server load function which works perfectly fine when the page is first loaded, but isnt suitable to load more data on a button press (as far as I understand).

Another possibility which I am aware of are form actions to post data, but I haven't been able to make them work with a 3rd party library.

A more universal approach seems to be the handle server hook. Is it suitable for my usecase? And how does an example request triggering the hook look like? In the docs only the example code for the server.js is given and it's not clear to me which requests will be caught there.

If this is actually a good idea might be a question for another post but if there are better / common approaches to achieve exactly what I am trying to do, feel free to leave some information. Most likely I have a wrong idea of some concepts, so pls correct me if I'm talking nonsense.

In any case, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am already using the server load function which works perfectly fine when the page is first loaded, but isnt suitable to load more data on a button press (as far as I understand).

That is incorrect. You can e.g. add query parameters via [`goto`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto) (which will be set as part of the URL in the [`searchParams`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/web-standards#url-apis-urlsearchparams)) or use [`invalidateAll`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-invalidateall) to just trigger `load` again.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it from a backend developer's perspective, the obvious answer  would be to make the API public but only **allow authenticated requests**. This can be implemented by adding server side authentication to your sveltekit endpoints.

A bit of a late answer but I think this is probably the correct solution to your problem. I recently posed a similar situation which led me to your question. I hope this helps.