# How to share data between +page.server.js and +server.js in SvelteKit

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

### Current Approach

In my `+page.server.js` file, I am fetching data from a database via the `load` function (a list of ALL users in the database) and then returning all the data to the browser. In the frontend, I have a search function which searches across all the fields of the data (metasearch). The problem with this approach is that right now the dataset is pretty small so the browser is able to contain the entire dataset in memory with minor lag but then this will definitely be an issue once the dataset grows.

### My Proposed Solution

I'll load the data from the database using the load function in the `+page.server.js` and access the same data in the `+server.js` file's `GET` function. Whenever the user types something in the `input`, it'll send the search query to the `GET` function of the `+server.js` where the filtering will happen (unlike my current implementation where the filtering was happening on the browser). Once filtered, the `GET` function will return only the filtered data.

How can I share data between the `load` function in `+page.server.js` and the `GET` function in `+server.js`?

Comment: Why the extra endpoint? You can have parameters directly via the query which is available in `load`.

Comment: Can you tell me more about how to go about using this approach? How can I pass in a query to the load function?

Comment: It's part of the `url` that is passed in. E.g. for `https://a.b/path?search=x` you can use `url.searchParams.get('search')` and it would return `'x'`.

Comment: Potential duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76626358/546730

Comment: Is there a reason you need to even have a load function in your `+page.server.js`? If you're making a GET request to the route, why not just put all your logic in `+server.js`? Posting a small repository or your file/route structure would be helpful.

Comment: @NashAnderson I am using the `+page.server.js` because I am using firebase auth for client side authentication. If I put the logic in the `+server.js` file, then everyone will have access to my API which I don't want